# How to Install PWA Studio for Live Server

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio

I have and AWS instance running Magento 2.3.5 with sample data and installed PWA Studio by following directions here:

https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/tutorials/pwa-studio-fundamentals/project-setup/

Node and Yarn is installed and all working and everything gets installed following those directions.

But, I cannot find any directions on how to use this on a live server.  After following the above instructions all I get is this URL:

https://pwa-studio-plo4s.local.pwadev:8091

And clicking that does not get anything in my browser.

I even tried following the Venia Storefront directions:

https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

But I can't tell if I am supposed to follow those directions instead of the other directions or in addition to those directions.  If I follow them in addition to it just installs it in another PWA directory.

I can't find anything that will tell me how to view this live using my domain name.  All of the setup to view the site/pwa is not clear at all.  Even sites like Nexcess, Webkul and CedCommerce that have PWA articles have been no help and just seem to repeat the same directions.

Can someone offer instructions on how to see this live? There has to be something/someone that has had success and good directions on how to get this implemented and working with a live site.

Thanks,
Stan

Comment: Did you get it working? I am facing same problem

Comment: No.  Documentation isn't clear enough and assumes you know everything.  If you find help please post back.

Comment: I do find a solution after all. I will post that as a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you already have or installed NodeJS >=10.14.1 and Yarn >=1.13.0 in your server. And also you have a running Magento 2 instance. Now follow below step by step.

In your Magento root directory run

```
git clone https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio.git
```

After clone complete go to pwa-studio folder

```
cd pwa-studio
```

Then run below command one by one

```
yarn install

yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept
```

Now set you backend url (site base url)

```
MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://mymagentosite.come/" \
CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN="sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk" \
yarn buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept
```

After that run below commands

```
yarn run build

yarn run watch:venia
```

Now what you need to do to connect you pwa-studio with your Magento is install Magento_UpwardConnector module

```
composer require magento/module-upward-connector
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Now you have to set connection between pwa-studio and magento by below commands. You have to give exact path of the **upward.yml** file.

```
bin/magento config:set -e web/upward/path /var/www/vhosts/mymagentosite/htdocs/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/dist/upward.yml
```

Thank you.